Flutter Not Sending Headers to Django Rest Framwork
I'm facing an issue with my Flutter app where the headers I'm trying to send to my Django backend aren't being received.
When I use Postman to send a request to my Django endpoint, the headers are received perfectly. However, when I make the same request from my Flutter app, the headers are missing.
Backend: Django Rest Framework (hosted on Azure Web Service)
Frontend: Flutter
when debug request header i made CustomJWTAuthentication
class CustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
        def authenticate(self, request):
                header = self.get_header(request)
                logger.info("header : ")
                logger.info( header)
    
                if header is None:
                    logger.info( " header is None:")
                    return None

it print header is None
azure logs
flutter code
flutter code  
Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any insights on why headers might not be sent from Flutter or how to debug further? Could this be related to Azure Web Service setup? Any help is appreciated!
update :
i found the problem
I've identified the issue—Flutter app was sending the request with HTTP instead of HTTPS

Please post your solution as an answer
